# Singular points on the restricton on a curve and its tangent

Tags: real-analysis

Be $f:\,\mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R$ a differentiable function and $\varphi(t)$ a differentiable curve in $\mathbb R^n$. Let's $\bf{x}'=\varphi(t')$ be a local minimum(or maximum) of the restriction $f(\varphi(t))$, is it possible to prove that $\bf x'$ is also a local minimum of the restriction of $f$ on the tangent to $\varphi$ at $\bf x'$?

If you want you can just use $\mathbb R^2$.

Answer (score 1):

No. In $\mathbb R^2$ let $f(x,y) = y-x^3 +y^2.$ Let $\varphi (t)=(t,t^3).$ Then $f\circ \varphi (t)  = t^6.$ Thus $f\circ \varphi $ has a strict local minimum at $t=0.$ But note $\varphi '(0) = (1,0).$ Thus the tangent direction is along the positive $x$-axis. In this direction we see $f\circ \varphi (t)  = -t^3,$ so $f\circ \varphi$ has no extremum at $t=0.$

Comment: oh, so it is actually false, can we prove at least that they have the same derivative?

Comment: If $\varphi'(t')\ne 0,$ the derivative of $f$ will be $0$ along any path tangent to $\varphi$ at the point in question.